# ValueError: Length mismatch: in Pandas + python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to match the column but unable to match unknown column name.

I am trying to get data from the website by clicking one by one on each page. I am facing problem while getting data unmatched column.

I tried:

```
    df = pd.DataFrame(entries)        
    df.columns = ['Bedrooms', 'Bathrooms', 'Super area', 
                  'Carpet area', 'Loading', 'Society', 
                  'Status', 'Posession by', 'Transaction type', 
                  'Price Breakup', 'Address', 'Landmarks', 
                  'Facing', 'Overlooking', 'Garden/Park Main Road',
                  'Flooring', 'Car Parking', 'Water Availability', 
                  'Status of Electricity', 'Lift', 'Units Available', 
                  'Furnishing', 'Authority Approval', 'Type of Ownership', 
                  'Brokerage Response', 'Amenities']

    print (df.iloc[[1]])

    data1 = pd.concat([df], ignore_index=True, axis=1)

    data1.iloc[[1]].to_csv('output.csv', mode='a')
```

Example:

I have some `df.columns` column names and want to match with new coming data row.

```
        0   1   2   3   4   5   6
1   2 See Dimension 2   1102 sqft   653 sqft    40% Eco Winds 2 Discussions on forum    Under Construction
2   2 See Dimension 2   1102 sqft               
3   2 See Dimension 2   1102 sqft   653 sqft    40% Eco Winds 2 Discussions on forum
```

as per above, all columns are not matching.

Error Getting: `ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 18 elements, new values have 26 elements`

Please suggest. Thank you in advance

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is not clear

Comment: @mad_, I have edited my question. Please check